# Correctly parsing through nested JSON using data model for multiple reuse. Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to find the best solution to parse through nested JSON. I know there are plenty examples of ways to parse JSON but I've been told the best practice is to make a **Class/Struct** model for the data I wish to pull out.

Here is a sample JSON data:

```
{
  "description": "Birds of Antarctica, grouped by family",
  "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_of_Antarctica",
  "birds": [
    {
      "family": "Albatrosses",
      "members": [
        "Wandering albatross",
        "Grey-headed albatross",
        "Black-browed albatross",
        "Sooty albatross",
        "Light-mantled albatross"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Terns",
      "members": [
        "Arctic tern",
        "Antarctic tern"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my Birds class:

```
class Birds {

    let family: String?
    let members: String?

    init?(json: JSON) {

        guard let family = json["family"] as? String, let members = json["members"] as? String else { return nil }

        self.family = family
        self.members = members

    }
}
```

This is my DataService:

```
typealias JSON = [String: Any]

class DataService {

    private init() {}
    static let shared = DataService()

    func getData(completion: (Data) -> Void) {

        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bird_data", ofType: "json") else {return}

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {

            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            completion(data)

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }
```

Finally this is how I call it in the viewController:

```
func getData() {
        DataService.shared.getData { (data) in
            do {
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? JSON else { return }

                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

So how would I get to print just the `family` and display it on a table for example.? Correct me if there is already a clear example for this.

I am aware there lots of third party to help like *SwiftyJSON* and *Gloss* but I'd like to understand it the standard way.

Comment: Do you just want to extract a value from a JSON and thats it or do you need the whole JSON represented as an object in your app for multiple reuses?

Comment: I want it as an object for multiple reuse.

Comment: Are you using swift 4?

Comment: Not currently, I'm still on Swift 3. But I will in the near future.

Comment: Use http://www.json4swift.com :)

Comment: @NikhilManapure I'm not looking to convert anything yet. I am still finding a solution for parsing JSON.

Comment: Try using [Almofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), it gives json response directly, Almofire is like de facto standard for such stuff.

Comment: But I want to be able to call and reuse the data wherever again. That's why I want to know how use a data model.

Comment: 1. Swift 4 does that really easily
2. it seems that you managed to parse the JSON and you created an init function for your Bird class - I'm not sure what is missing... instead of printing the json object you serialized send it to the Bird class

Comment: When I print the JSON it just gets me the entire JSON rather than the specific attribute. Could this be because I need to serialize it? If so, could you demonstrate how this can be achieved please.

Comment: @inspector_60 I'm trying to get it to now display on a table for example.

Comment: You've created a Bird class and initiated it with the JSON so now just use it... (I'm not sure what exactly you are missing)

Comment: Then why can't I do this? `cell.textLabel?.text = Birds[indexPath.row].family`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think depending on the structure of your json, you need to form two model classes one for the whole json and one for the individual birds, so you can do something like this :

```
class Bird {

    let family: String?
    let members: [String]?

    init?(json: JSON) {

        guard let family = json["family"] as? String, let members = json["members"] as? [String] else { return nil }

        self.family = family
        self.members = members

    }
}


class JsonData {

    var birds: [Bird]?
    var description: String?
    var sourceUrl: String?

    init?(json: JSON) {

        guard let description = json["description"] as? String, let sourceUrl = json["source"] as? String, let birds = json["birds"] as? [JSON] else { return nil }

        self.description = description
        self.sourceUrl = sourceUrl
        self.birds = [Bird]()
        for singleBird in birds {
            let singleBirdObj = Bird(singleBird)
            self.birds?.append(singleBirdObj)
            //you can add birds to shared manager array like this (after discussion with OP)
            BirdManager.shared.appendBird(singleBirdObj)
        }

    }

}


func getData() {
        DataService.shared.getData { (data) in
            do {
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? JSON else { return }

                let jsonDataObject = JsonData(json)
                //here you have jsonDataObject that has all the json data

                print(print(jsonDataObject?.description))
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in the JsonData class saying: `Type 'Any?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'` at the for loop.

Comment: @mninety5 I have updated the answer, please check, I have added `as? [JSON]`

Comment: I've literally copied your code but it still giving me the same error :/

Comment: @mninety5 can you please tell at which line does the error occur?

Comment: `for singleBird in json["birds"] {`

Comment: @mninety5 sorry my mistake, please use `for singleBird in birds` instead of `for singleBird in json["birds"]`

Comment: Now in the last line `Value of type '[Bird]?' has no member 'append'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156093/discussion-between-3stud1ant3-and-mninety5).

Comment: Sorry, quick question, if I wanted to go into _members_, how would I achieve this as it is an Array and not String like _family_ so I am struggling to get on the table as discussed.

Comment: @mninety5 I think you can try this: `BirdManager.shared.birds[indexPath.row].members[0]`

Comment: Ok, this gets me the array of all the first member. However what if I wanted to get an array of all members?

Comment: @mninety5 you can get the array like this: `if let membersArr = BirdManager.shared.birds[indexPath.row].members as? [String] { print(membersArr)}`

Comment: This is correct. But I realise it's not what I need. I just thought I could display the entire members array. But I probably need to create a separate table specifically for all members or it'll get ugly.

Comment: You can use sections in tableview to show the family as the section header and members as the rows of that section

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swift 4, you can use Codable protocol like this:

```
struct Bird: Codable {
    let family: String
    let members: [String]
}

struct Root: Codable {
    let description: String
    let source: URL
    let birds: [Bird]
}
```

You can try it in Swift Playground like this:

```
let jsonData = """
{
  "description": "Birds of Antarctica, grouped by family",
  "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_of_Antarctica",
  "birds": [
    {
      "family": "Albatrosses",
      "members": [
        "Wandering albatross",
        "Grey-headed albatross",
        "Black-browed albatross",
        "Sooty albatross",
        "Light-mantled albatross"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Terns",
      "members": [
        "Arctic tern",
        "Antarctic tern"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let parsedObject = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
```

You can read more info (e.g. custom keys, custom date parsing, etc) about Swift 4 Codable protocol here: http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/