# Use images with local JSON data Swift

Tags: ios, json

I have a local JSON data which populates my views when the app loads. I am now trying to load local images and append them to the necessary objects.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
    "description": "Birds of Antarctica, grouped by family",
    "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_of_Antarctica",
    "birds": [
              {
              "bio": "Albatrosses are highly efficient in the air, using dynamic soaring and slope soaring to cover great distances with little exertion. They feed on squid, fish and krill by either scavenging, surface seizing or diving. Albatrosses are colonial, nesting for the most part on remote oceanic islands, often with several species nesting together.",
              "family": "Albatrosses",
              "imageURL": "albatross.jpg",
              "members": [
                          "Wandering albatross",
                          "Grey-headed albatross",
                          "Black-browed albatross",
                          "Sooty albatross",
                          "Light-mantled albatross"
                          ]
              },
              {
              "bio": "Terns and shags are medium-to-large birds, with body weight in the range of 0.35–5 kilograms (0.77–11.02 lb) and wing span of 45–100 centimetres (18–39 in). The majority of species have dark feathers. The bill is long, thin and hooked. Their feet have webbing between all four toes. All species are fish-eaters, catching the prey by diving from the surface.",
              "family": "Terns",
              "imageURL": "terns.jpg",
              "members": [
                          "Arctic tern",
                          "Antarctic tern"
                          ]
              }
              ]
}
```

I'm able to get the family, bio and members using the suggestions made here: [Correctly parsing through nested JSON using data model for multiple reuse. Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602937/correctly-parsing-through-nested-json-using-data-model-for-multiple-reuse-swift/46603942?noredirect=1#comment80169987_46603942).

In my BirdCell class which is used to populate my table I have this:

```
class BirdCell: UITableViewCell {

    var bird: Bird!
    var imageUrl: String!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var birdImage: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        birdImage.image = nil
        imageUrl = bird.imageUrl?.absoluteString

        if let imageUrl = bird.imageUrl {
            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: imageUrl)
            birdImage.kf.setImage(with: resource)

            if birdImage.image == nil {

                birdImage.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
            } else {

            }
        }
        nameLbl.text = bird.family

    }
```

I am using **Kingfisher** to cache the image. I am getting a `nil` when trying to cache the image through.

Feel free to let me know if my method is not the best practice for what I am attempting and give me directions on how to achieve it.

Comment: Your imageUrl are actually not urls. Maybe thats why

Comment: @mninety5 : When initializing your "BirdClass" are you sure `image` string is not nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestions from the comments below I realised that I was not supposed to be trying to get the imageURL as it is a local file and instead just return an image object with a specified filename.

This is how I achieved it:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    birdImage.image = UIImage(named: bird.image!)
    nameLbl.text = bird.family
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How are the images added to your project? I'd guess they're in your Images.xcassets file? In which case just double check that the names in the JSON match up to the names in the asset file. Why are you trying to create Image URLs if the file is local?

When are you setting the *bird* property on your cells - looks like this could be nil when the cell is getting reused? I'd suggest moving your code from `prepareForReuse()` to your own method and calling this from `cellForRowAt:`. Something like:

```
func updateWithBird(bird: Bird) {
    birdImage.image = UIImage(named: bird.image)
    nameLbl.text = bird.family
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I've just done `birdImage.image = UIImage(named: bird.image!)` and it works as well.